# Will there be arbitrage if we don't have the $dB_t$ term?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, finance, stochastic-analysis

Assume you have a filtered probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P,\mathcal{F}_t)$. Lets say you have the financial market with the bank process:

$$dR_0(t,\omega)=\rho(\omega,t)R_0(t,\omega)dt,$$

where $\rho$ is a progressively measurable process and it is assumed that $P(\int_0^T|\rho(\omega,t)R(\omega,t)|dt<\infty)=1$. And you have a risky asset which is modelled by

$$dR_1(\omega,t)=\mu(\omega,t)dt+\sigma(\omega,t)dB_t,$$

where $\mu, \sigma$ are progressively measurable and $P(\int_0^T|\mu(\omega,t)|dt<\infty)=1$ and $P(\int_0^T|\sigma(\omega,t)|^2dt<\infty)=1$.

Now assume that $\sigma(\omega,t)=0$. Then the risky asset is just modelled by

$$dR_1(\omega,t)=\mu(\omega,t)dt.$$

**Can we show that we have arbitrage in this case?**

The reason I suspect this to be true is that if we we instead had a time-discrete market with $t_0=0<t_1<t_2<\cdots<t_n=T$ and we modelled it by

$$\Delta R_1(\omega,t_i)=R_1(\omega,t_{i+1})-R_1(\omega,t_{i})=\mu(\omega,t_i)\cdot \Delta t_t,$$

then we would have had arbitrage. Because since $\mu$ is adapted, it is known at time $t_i$ hence at time $t_i$ we would know what the value of the risky asset would be at time $t_{i+1}$. We would also know what the value of the bank process would be at time $t_{i+1}$ at time $t_i$. So we could either borrow money and buy the stock or short the stock and put money in the bank, depending on what gave highest return. **However, can we show that it will lead to arbitrage in the time-continuous case as well?**

**Update**

I think I have a solution. It goes like this:

Look at the dsicounted process $R_1/R_0$, this is an Itö-process by looking at the function $F(x,y)=x/y$ and noting that $R_1/R_0=F(R_1,R_0)$. F satisfies the hypothesis in the Itö-formula since $R_0\ne 0$. Since $dR_1$ and $dR_0$ don't have any $dB$ terms it follows from Itös formula that $dF(R_1,R_0)$ don't have any $dB$ terms. Hence

$$\frac{R_1(t)}{R_0(t)}=\frac{R_1(0)}{R_0(0)}+\int_0^tK(\omega,s)ds,$$

where we find $K$ from Itö's formula. Since Itös formula tells us that $R_1/R_0$ is an Itö-process we have that

$$P\left(\int_0^T|K(\omega,t)|dt<\infty\right)=1.$$

The fundamental theorem of asset-pricing tells us that there is no arbitrage if and only if there exist an equivalent local martingale measure $Q$ where $R_1/R_0$ is a local martingale. Assume for contradiction that $Q$ exists.

Now we have that $$R_1/R_0$$ is defined $\omega$-wise $P$-a.s. And since $Q$ is equivalent to $P$ we must also have

$$Q\left(\int_0^T|K(\omega,t)|dt<\infty\right)=1.$$

Now look at $K$, $\omega$-wise. Then it is an $L^1[0,T]$-function. And it is known that $F(s)=\int_0^t f(s)ds$ has bounded variation for $f \in L^1[0,T]$.

Hence under $Q$ we have that $R_1/R_0$ is a continuous local martingale with finite variation. This means that it is constant. Hence

$$Q(\{\omega: R_1(\omega,\cdot)/R_0(\omega,\cdot)=\text{Constant}\})=1.$$

But since $P$ and $Q$ are equivalent we have

$$P(\{\omega: R_1(\omega,\cdot)/R_0(\omega,\cdot)=\text{Constant}\})=1.$$

This means that

$$R_1(\omega,t)=R_0(\omega,t)\cdot M(\omega).$$

But this also holds for $t=0$ hence

$$R_1(\omega,t)=\frac{R_1(0)}{R_0(0)}\cdot R_0(\omega,t),$$

Hence we are limited to the trivial case where the risky asset is a multiple of the bank-process.

Comment: Actually I didn't notice you used arithmetic brownian motion instead of geometric. Is this deliberate?

Comment: @fesman Yes, I tried to do it as general as possible.

Comment: Ok I now corrected the answer.

Comment: @user394334 Could you, please, explain what is meant by "$R_1/R_0$ is defined $\omega$-wise $P$-a.s."?

Answer (score 4):

Intuitively it is quite easy to see that there is arbitrage as long as the drifts are unequal with positive probability. Here you would invest in the asset with higher drift and sell the asset with lower drift.

More formally you could use the result that the model is free of arbitrage if and only if there exists a risk neutral measure under which the stock price discounted with the bond is a martingale.

Let $\tilde{\mu}(\omega,t)=\frac{\mu(\omega,t)}{R_1(\omega,t)}$ and $\tilde{\sigma}(\omega,t)=\frac{\sigma(\omega,t)}{R_1(\omega,t)}$.

If $\tilde{\mu}(\omega,t) = \rho(\omega,t)$ the physical and risk neutral measures coincide. However, if not under this measure $B_t$ evolves as

$$dB_t^{Q}=\frac{\tilde{\mu}(\omega,t)-\rho(\omega,t)}{\tilde{\sigma}(\omega,t)}+dB_t$$

(see any book on math finance). Now if $\sigma(\omega,t)=0$ this risk neutral measure does not exist. There is no measure under which the discounted stock price were a martingale, hence there is arbitrage.

Comment: Thank you, I have two questions. 1. Does this take into account that the SDE are different for the bank and the risky asset?, the bank will be geometric? 2. From what I understand one can show that if one can define $dB^Q$ that way, then the equivalent martingale measure exists? But does the converse hold, that is, if if can not define it that way, since we then devide by zero, then an equivalent martingale measure does not exist? Also, how do you get that it actually works, does a specific book have this equations?

Comment: @user394334 Yes this takes that into account. You can check Björks book. If the vol is zero you essentially have two bank accounts each with different returns under any measure. The latter discounted with the former cannot be a martingale.

Comment: But what is the actual reason that $R_1(t)/R_0(t)$ cannot be a (local) martingale under an equivalent measure?

Comment: I found a solution myself, I updated it in the main post if you are interested. But thank you very much for your help.